# Mean/sd: Figure out the mean and standard deviation for each group. And then the one closer to one of the groups is assigned that

Tags: r, statistics, probability

This is my data.

I'm trying to figure out the `mean/sd` of groups `A` and groups `B`, but I'm at a loss:

```
library(ggplot2)
n <- 10000
df <- data.frame(
  cats=rep(c("A","B"), each=n), 
  vals=c(rnorm(n, mean=10, sd=2), rnorm(n, mean=20, sd=2))
)
ggplot(df, aes(vals, color=cats)) +
  geom_density()
```

Comment: Not clear on what  you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr::summarize

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(cats) %>% summarize(sd = sd(vals), mean = mean(vals))

cats     sd  mean
<fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      1.99  10.0
2 B      1.98  20.0
```